# Why shouldn't you create a custom uri scheme?

Tags: naming, web, standards

In setting up deep linking to android and iOS apps, I've made some use of custom URI schemes, and they work great, especially as a fallback when the mechanism that allows maps from `http:` fails (as often happens with technology).

However, I've noticed one answerer [strongly recommend against creating your own url scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android?noredirect=1&lq=1) ([and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android?noredirect=1&lq=1)). To me, it seems reasonable to create my own URI scheme, especially when namespaced appropriately.

I looked up the [w3c docs on URIs](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/) and the [RFC that covers creating new URL schemes (RFC2718)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2718.txt) doesn't have any recommendations against creation of one's own URI scheme.

The handful of google results show me arguments against creation of *new* generic URI schemes, but the situation of app-specific provisional schemes still seems like a very useful one.

Answer (score 9):

1. Custom URI schemes require your app to be already installed.  There are other methods available that do not, such as [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) or [App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html).
2. You can't prevent another app from stomping on your URI scheme if it is installed after yours.
3. Universal and app links are more secure-- if you own the domain, the links are guaranteed to follow the configuration that you have set up, because the configuration files are held on the server.
4. Universal and app links allow fallback behaviors, e.g. if the app isn't installed you can open a web page instead, or direct the user to the app store.